# If I do not go into a party wall dispute, can I still appoint a surveyor to ensure I am protected against any damages?

Tags: foundation

I live in the UK.  My neighbour has presented me with a party wall notice; saying they intend to build a wall close to the boundary, with foundations encroaching onto my land.

While I do not in principle oppose what what they are doing, I am concerned that there will be damage to my property.

I do not understand whether I should go into a party wall dispute with them.

So my question is:

**If I do *not* go into a dispute, can I still appoint a surveyor to ensure I am protected against any damages?**

Comment: This might be a question for your lawyer, not a bunch of dimwits on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely best answered by a local professional, but the UK government has an easy-to-read guide to "Party Wall" law:
https://www.gov.uk/party-wall-etc-act-1996-guidance

That document includes many FAQs (including the ones you've asked here), sample letters, requirements about giving consent, etc.

It's not clear from your question what you're concerned about, but if you have a building near the boundary I think it would be wise to avail yourself of your rights, particularly regarding proper preparation and security for damages.